# Set HTTP header for all PHP scripts via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I code same lines all PHP programs at one of my projects. Is it possible to do this at .htaccess for a directory? And how?

PHP codes:

```
Header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8');
Header("Cache-Control: no-transform");
```

Thanks any help.
Best regards.

Yusuf Akyol

Comment: What do you meen exactly? I havent understand this very well...

Comment: You should be aware that most clients don’t understand *real* XHTML. You should at least add some content negotiation.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this with .htaccess (or in Apache config), you can use [Apache module mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header), like this:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
Header set Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"
```

A search on [htaccess set header](http://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+set+header) gives you many more examples of this.

Comment: Won't this will set all files to be application/xhtml+xml, including images, javascript and stylesheets?

Comment: Hi,
Is it possible send a complete .htaccess codes for these? 
My htaccess has only these codes:
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
   Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
   Header set Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"
</FilesMatch>
I think I had to do more. Because I get error.
Best regards.

Comment: @robertc: you are right; the OP said "for directory", so this would apply to all files in the directory.

Comment: @unknown (google): Looks OK to me, this should *be* the whole .htaccess code. Do you have mod_headers installed and enabled?

Also, you get *an error*. That doesn't tell us very much, please be more specific - what kind of error? Also, what error is shown for this in the Apache error log?

Comment: Hi,
I enabled mod_headers. Now everything is OK.
Thanks again and again.
Best regards.

Comment: @unknown (google): You're welcome. If this solved your problem, mark the answer "accepted" (the checkbox below the answer's score).

Answer (score 6):

For the content type you use [AddType from mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html).  Assuming all your files have `.php` extensions:

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml .php
```

Caching is set in [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html), but you need [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) to set Cache-Control:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: all of you... 
best regards...
Best regards.