# How to set default php header()

Tags: php, header

When I create the non-English pages (for example, Russian) I have to use header() to set page's charset (I use UTF-8):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But all my pages should have UTF-8 charset, is there a propery in php to set it by default (I mean: I don't want to set it every time).

Comment: hope it would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139699/set-http-header-for-all-php-scripts-via-htaccess-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .htaccess file to do it:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

If you want something a bit more robust, you can specify this charset type for only specific file types:

```
<FilesMatch ".(htm|html|css|js)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</FilesMatch>
```

Also see this article for other ways of doing it:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

Comment: So, to set language I should use: AddLanguage ru-Ru .html .htm .css .js, or something else?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You can also use the `DefaultLanguage` directive e.g. `DefaultLanguage en-US`.

Answer (score 1):

**The entire .htaccess file**

Let's take a look at the entire htaccess config file, then go through all the configuration options.

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

cache images/pdf docs for 10 days

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
  Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 2 days

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use define() set default charset.

From PHP documentaion http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

```
$text = '';//some russian content
define('CHARSET', preg_match( '/[\p{Cyrillic}]/u', $text) ? 'windows-1251' : 'utf-8');// or fetch charset from DB some other resource
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.CHARSET);
```

Comment: I already had said: I don't want to use header(), I want to set headers default values!

Comment: You can use .htaccess to set default charset for your pages but what will you do when language used in your page vary.In that cae you will need to wrote some algorithem that could detect charset

Comment: My website is only on English/Russian, so I need only UTF-8 (or windows-1251)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue got not much with PHP. Your httpd is incorrectly configured (i.e. on many distros Apache used to come with `AddDefaultCharset` set to `Latin1` by default.